# Is $C(\mathbb R)$ Separable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm working on an exercise from Carother's chapter11 of Real Analysis that talking about Space of Continuous Functions:

Here, $C(\Bbb R)$ is the set of continuous real-valued functions on $\Bbb R$, with topology induced by the metric 
$$
d(f,g)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} {d_n(f,g)\over 1+d_n(f,g)},
$$
where, for each $n$,
$$
d_n(f,g)=\max_{|t|\le n} |f(t)-g(t)|.
$$

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: @DavidMitra: How to type in this metric? I'm not familiar with Latex.

Comment: There you go.${}$

Comment: @DavidMitra: Much appreciate

Comment: @DavidMitra: I think I need to use Dini's theorem to prove something.

Comment: This should work:   For each $n$, $C_n=C[-n,n]$ is separable in this metric. Each $C_n$ has a countable dense subset. Take the union of these and extend the functions  continuously to all of $\Bbb R$.  Show that this, countable set, is dense. (Use, for fixed $\epsilon>0$, $d(f,g)<\epsilon+\sum_{n=1}^m {d_n(f,g)\over1+d_n(f,g)}$ for sufficiently large $m$.)

Comment: @DavidMitra: How did you get idea of the problem on metric definition, Im very interested in.

Comment: The metric you give is a common metric used to induce the topology of compact convergence on a $\sigma$-compact metric space.

Comment: @DavidMitra - Wait, this says that $C(\mathbb{R})$ is **not** separable? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450318/show-c-mathbbr-is-not-separable

Comment: @TaylorRendon: norm is different

Comment: @BearandBunny - ah, good catch. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

HINT: It is enough to prove that $C[a,b]$ is separable. (Why?). But from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem such continuous functions can be approximated by polynomials. And we can take polynomials with rational coefficients.

Comment: Stone-Weierstrass theorem does work on compact set. But here R is not compact

Comment: @Frank_W $C[a,b]$ is compact. And $R$ is a sum of countable number of intervals.

Comment: suppose there does exist a countable dense set F. Enumerate F={f1,f2,f3,....}. Define g at x=1,2,3,... and the connect end points of interval [k,k+1] linearly, |f1(x) - g(x)| =1 at x=1, |f2(x) - g(x)| =1 at x=2, ..., then g cannot be in ε-ball of dense set F and g does be continuous in C(R).

Comment: Kola B. please notice my example. is that correct?

Comment: @Frank_W No. You can find far elements even is so obvious case as reals with natural metric, but you want to find close elements.

Comment: What did you mean by close elements? I mean g that I build will not be in the ε-ball produced by dense set F which will prove F actually not be dense, is that correct?

Comment: @Frank_W But why we consider $f_i$  at $i$?. There are infinitely many of them in, e.g., $x=1$ and of course some of them are farther than $\varepsilon$ from a fixed value $g(1)$.

Comment: see. on (-infinity,0], g=0;[0,1],|$f_1$(x) - g(x)| =1 at x=1;[1,2],|$f_2$(x) - g(x)| =1 at x=2;...;[k,k+1],|$f_{k+1}$(x) - g(x)| =1 at x=k+1;.... And I connect both endpoints on each interval linearly that produce a polygonal function being continuous. Then for  ε>0.5, there is no positive integer n such that |$f_m$(x)-g(x)|< ε which proves F is not dense. By contradiction, no such countable dense subset F .